# In SAS, one variable cannot use the other when creating a dataset

Tags: sas, dataset

I am creating a dataset where one variable is generated from a distribution using the other variable as an hyperparameter. However, it seems that I cannot do that. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
%LET n=10; *sample size;
DATA d;
DO id = 1 TO &n;
 x = RAND('BERNoulli', 0.5);
 y = RAND('bernoulli', 1/(1+exp(-1+x)));
 output;
 END;
RUN;

proc print d;
```

My dataset looks like the following:

[image: results]

I cannot understand why variable y cannot use variable x. Any hints?

Comment: If I copy paste your code it won't run for me. I get "Integration technology has failed to submit the code" error. BUT, if I retype everything exactly like you, it works. Even variable y works just fine. Weird.

Comment: One hint something very strange is going on is that you have two variables named `x` in your print out.  That is impossible.  So one of the x's is not actually an x.  I would assume the one in the second assignment statement.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. I get 0's and 1's for x and y.

Comment: @StuSztukowski Copy/paste of his code? Or retyped one? Because for me copy/pasted one doesn't work, but if I retype it exactly, it works fine. Which doesn't make sense...

Comment: Retyped. Copy/paste does not work for me. I notice the syntax does not highlight properly when copying/pasting, so I'm guessing there must be hidden characters in it.

Comment: Thank you guys! Once I retyped the code, it worked for me also. There are hidden characters in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you not notice that the dataset `d` has two variables with seem to have the name `x`, but that one of these names in not left aligned?

Remove the invisible unicode character 'e28083'x in front of `x =` and `y =` and your code will work.